# Is it possible for a non japanese anime/manga artist to draw and color anime/manga authentically?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production, mangaka

If a westerner or other foreigners draws anime/manga art in their style the drawing,coloring,etc style will not resemble that of a japanese because it is not 100% authentic japanese style

However would it help if they went to japanese schools to tutored by japanese teachers(as it is happening in reality) for anime/manga in order draw and color anime/manga authentically to avoid inauthenticity ?

Comment: Many of the questions you pose are already answered in the dupe; namely, we as westerners see "style", Japanese only care about the loanword.

Comment: @Makoto I like to argue about this topic,no one is responding in that page

Comment: @DanielRigg come to chat

Comment: Two things:  this is a Q&A site, not a forum; questions and answers are still relevant to this day, and second, there's not much to *argue* since we do feel that it's been concisely answered.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-

Comment: What is "100% authentic Japanese style"?... [this is Hatsune Miku by a random Japanese artist](https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=63809376) and [this is another Hatsune Miku by another random Japanese artist](https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=63803594). On the other hand, [this is Hatsune Miku by a random Russian](http://dav-19.deviantart.com/art/Miku-Append-213114328) and [this is another Hatsune Miku by a random Malaysian](http://crazy-megame.deviantart.com/art/chibi-miku-192135466).

Comment: @AkiTanaka to describe authentic I mean how faces,hair,clothes,etc are drawn,inked and colored even how japanese draw,ink and color

Comment: if that's what you mean by authentic well then of course everyone can learn how to draw like that, see these fanart made by Korean https://www.pixivision.net/en/a/2421

Comment: @Darjeeling but would it require work hard to do it like that?

Comment: yes, you need to work hard and lot of practice